# Total of an array using only top 3 values

Tags: php, mysql, database, limit

With help from a fellow member I have been able to add together the values of an array called by a MySQL query. However, the code I have is adding up all values.

```
$top_1st = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(1ET)/10 AS top_1st 
FROM scoring_data WHERE Competition='$competition' AND Club='$row[Club]' 
AND Team='$row[Team]' ORDER BY 1ET DESC LIMIT 0, 3"));

echo $top_1st[0] ;
```

I have used

```
LIMIT 0, 3
```

as I only want to add up the highest 3 values from the query returned, but this doesn't seem to work.

Apologies if there is a simple solution; novice skills really being put to the test!

EDIT

Advice from @marc-b (thanks) has led me to this, however it is giving a blank return.

```
$top_1st = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
SELECT SUM(1ET)/10
FROM (
SELECT 1ET AS top_1st FROM scoring_data WHERE Competition='$competition' AND
Club='$row[Club]' AND Team='$row[Team]' ORDER BY 1ET DESC LIMIT 0, 3 ) "));
echo $top_1st[0] ;
```

Comment: Not really related, but you're using a deprecated mysql API which can (potentially) cause security issues. Use ODB instead.

Comment: You know, it's OK to break code up into several lines, likethewayweseparatewordswithspacesandsentenceswithparagraphsandpunctuationbecauseyouknow it makes it easier to read.

Comment: I thought I had done so but didn't realise one or two words went over the limit. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the top 3 values first, then sum in another query, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(foo)
FROM (
    SELECT whatever AS foo
    FROM ...
    LIMIT 3
)
```

The limit has to be applied in the inner query. Otherwise you'd be summing up to a single row, which would then fall within the 3-row limit anyways.

Comment: I think you're missing the ORDER there

Comment: @MightyPork I think it's included in the ellipsis

Comment: I have edited the code (above) however it is producing a blank result now. I've tried removing each part of the code to see what is not making it work but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: never chain db calls. you're assuming everything worked properly. ALWAYS check for failure: `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error()); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.